# Example of invertebrates that are attracted to heat?

Tags: zoology, microbiology

I would like to test a device that outputs heat in order to attract schistosome parasites in water. However, I would like to use a substitute, since I cannot find schistosome parasites for sale.

**Are there any organisms that are attracted to heat and are easily accessible?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tendency to be attracted toward heat is called [**thermotaxis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermotaxis%C2%A8).

**Documented cases**

Thermotaxis has been documented in

- *C. elegans*

  - [Ploff and Sokut 2010](http://www.pnas.org/content/74/5/2007.short)
- Slime molds *Meloidogyne incognita*

  - [Pline et al 1988](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2618849/)
- *Drosophila*

  - [Rosenweig et al. 2004](http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/19/4/419.short)
- Mosquito *Aedes Aegypti*

  - [Patterson and Brown 2009](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-entomological-research/article/studies-of-the-responses-of-the-female-aedes-mosquito-part-iii-the-response-of-aedes-aegypti-l-to-a-warm-body-and-its-radiation/92A58119A0704CFA491B3A2B253B0F5E)
- Lake sculpin (*Cottus extensus*) larvea

  - [Wurtsbaugh and Neverman 1988](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v333/n6176/abs/333846a0.html)
- Mammalian sperm cells

  - [Bahat et al. 2003](http://www.nature.com/nm/journal/v9/n2/full/nm0203-149.html)

The best documentation is on *C.elegans*. There are probably many undocumented species that display thermotaxis but above are the only documented cases I could find.

Many of these species are easy to find in biology labs. Mammalian sperm cells are very easy to find if you are a male but it may take complex methodology to observe thermotaxis on cells. Bigger organisms are of greater interest. *Drosophila* might be the way to go.

**Do you really need to test with another species?**

Whether the test is a good idea was not part of your question but I thought I would comment on it anyway!

I am wondering whether testing your device on a different species is of much interest to you. Testing that your device creates a thermal gradient is sure of interest but one species may react very differently to a specific gradient than another one and it feels a priori to me that you'd be waisting your time by testing it on a different species.

I think it would be more interesting to just place thermometers (if you have access to good accurate thermometers) along space and measure temperature to ensure that a gradient exists and make sure that the temperatures and steep of gradient are within the range of what schistosome may experience in nature.

I am not involved in this research and you may have good reasons of yours of testing your device on a different species.